# How to implement edit functionality in ThymeLeaf in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html)
I see delete functionality for each row:

> 7.6 Dynamic fields
>
> Thanks to the advanced form-field binding capabilities in Spring MVC,
>   we can use complex Spring EL expressions to bind dynamic form fields
>   to our form-backing bean. This will allow us to create new Row objects
>   in our SeedStarter bean, and to add those rows’ fields to our form at
>   user request.
>
> In order to do this, we will need a couple of new mapped methods in
>   our controller, which will add or remove a row from our SeedStarter
>   depending on the existence of specific request parameters:
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping(value="/seedstartermng", params={"addRow"})
> public String addRow(final SeedStarter seedStarter, final BindingResult bindingResult) {
>     seedStarter.getRows().add(new Row());
>     return "seedstartermng";
> }
>
> @RequestMapping(value="/seedstartermng", params={"removeRow"})
> public String removeRow(
>         final SeedStarter seedStarter, final BindingResult bindingResult, 
>         final HttpServletRequest req) {
>     final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("removeRow"));
>     seedStarter.getRows().remove(rowId.intValue());
>     return "seedstartermng";
> }
> ```
>
> And now we can add a dynamic table to our form:
>
> ```
> <table>
>   <thead>
>     <tr>
>       <th th:text="#{seedstarter.rows.head.rownum}">Row</th>
>       <th th:text="#{seedstarter.rows.head.variety}">Variety</th>
>       <th th:text="#{seedstarter.rows.head.seedsPerCell}">Seeds per cell</th>
>       <th>
>         <button type="submit" name="addRow" th:text="#{seedstarter.row.add}">Add row</button>
>       </th>
>     </tr>
>   </thead>
>   <tbody>
>     <tr th:each="row,rowStat : *{rows}">
>       <td th:text="${rowStat.count}">1</td>
>       <td>
>         <select th:field="*{rows[__${rowStat.index}__].variety}">
>           <option th:each="var : ${allVarieties}" 
>                   th:value="${var.id}" 
>                   th:text="${var.name}">Thymus Thymi</option>
>         </select>
>       </td>
>       <td>
>         <input type="text" th:field="*{rows[__${rowStat.index}__].seedsPerCell}" />
>       </td>
>       <td>
>         <button type="submit" name="removeRow" 
>                 th:value="${rowStat.index}" th:text="#{seedstarter.row.remove}">Remove row</button>
>       </td>
>     </tr>
>   </tbody>
> </table>
> ```
>
> Quite a lot of things to see here, but not much we should not
>   understand by now… except for one strange thing:

Now I won't implement edit functionality.

Ideas?